# Activity sometimes finish by it self

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Having troubles in an app im making. When wanting to go to another activty, it some time does, but other times it dons't.

Having a bit of a problem with an app im in the process of making. In my i app i use a couple of spinners, to allow the user to have a few selections, where he can choose an option. Depending on the selected value, some is done. One of these is the option to search for a list, where it first time go fine to my activity with the list in it, the second time, it wont go there. After trying around abit, it seems like it just goes straight back to the place where i have the spinners the second time.

When spinner choose to search:

```
parent.setSelection(0);
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemListActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("sender", "showItemList");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code within the new activity:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
if (sender.equals("showItemList")) {
    fragment = new ShowItemList();
} else if (sender.equals("editItemList")) {
    fragment = new EditItemList();
} else if (sender.equals("deleteItemList")) {
    fragment = new DeleteItemList();
    deleteItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (fragment != null) { getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.itemLayout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Code within the fragment:

```
adapter = null;
showItems = null;
showItems = inf.findViewById(R.id.itemList);
itemDBAList = vars.getItems();
showItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
showItems.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
adapter = new ShowItemAdapter(itemDBAList);
showItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As said, first time it runs fine, getting into the expected place, and lets me do the search, the second time however, it seems like it is called back instatly, like finish() was called on the ItemListActivity after it launches. Have tried running though it with the debugger, and it does seems to doing what it should, expected getting finished.

Comment: are you getting value from intent?  in your code, you are not catching any intent.

Comment: I am able to get into the intent, when running though the debugger, and have also tested to see if the intent goes of, with System.out.println in my code, both in the activity itself and the fragment, where both where written out.

Comment: in intent why u passing getActivity() instead of this? is you open activity from fragment or what? kindly paste full activity code

Comment: Are passing the new activity within a fragment, but thanks for asking for full code, as that made me see, where i had made an error. Had made a variable that was part of my variable package i used around my app, and had forgotten to reset after used, which would ofcourse bring up this exact problem. Futher testing before your ask, also showed that if had used another of my searches, i could do for the first one again.